# icon not repainting in JoptionPane java

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, imageicon

My program captures the screen's images, resizes and represents them in a JoptionPane icon filed so that the user can decide weather or not to save them. 
The prob is that after performing Joption.cancel, the icon shows the previous image the next time the user captures the screen image. in Joption.ok case it works fine.
Any idea why this happens? the snapshots themselves are well rendered(every snapshot captures the very current screen image but the icon shows the previous one once cancel has been clicked) .

```
  rszedSnp=ImageMagick.resize(origSnp_name,30);
ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon(rszedSnp);
    String userIput = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            new JFrame(),
                           "Save as:\n",
                           "taking screen shot",
                           JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                           icon ,
                          null,
                          origSnp_name);
```

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: new JFrame() is 1st. of wrong ideas ........., follows advice described in 1st. comment here, sure only in the case if you want to do something with ...

Comment: Ive managed on extending JDialog.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem by using JDialog, with an implemented JPanel containing a JLabel holding the image, instead of using an image icon in the JOptionPane#showInputDialog function. .

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(image));
resize(img);
JLabel lbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
lbl.setVisible(true);

JPanel imgPan = new JPanel();
imgPan.add(new JScrollPane(lbl))

JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
JPanel globalPan = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
globalPan.add(imgPan);
dialog.add( globalPan );

dialog.pack();
dialog.setVisible(true);
```